# Negative of a qubit state

Tags: quantum-state

I have a quick question: Is the qubit state $|\psi\rangle$ the same as $-|\psi\rangle$?

Comment: Be careful with the answers below, the two are certainly not equal! Personally I would not call them "the same". Also note that if a phase is not global (that is, if you have a state such as $|\psi_1\rangle + e^{i\phi}|\psi_2\rangle$) the phase matters... a lot!

Comment: @sebhofer does your concern boil down to a distinction between "indistinguishable" and "equal?"  Either way can you offer an answer to highlight your concern?

Comment: @MarkS In part yes. After all, we would never call the vectors (1,0) and (-1,0) (in the Euclidean space) equal. Also, as I pointed out above, I think it's important to stress that this is only true for a global phase, and not for the phases in a superposition. This might not be clear if you call them equal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

States $|\psi\rangle$ and $-|\psi\rangle$ differ in global phase only and thus they are indistinguishable. So, the answer is: **state $-|\psi\rangle$ is the equivalent to $|\psi\rangle$**.

The global phase in this case is $\pi$ because $\mathrm{e}^{i\pi} = -1$.

Comment: Indistinguishability does not necessarily mean that they are equal. Yes, we cannot distinguish them from each other, but they are different.

Comment: @nippon Aren't states rays in a Hilbert space (and thus $-\psi$ and $+\psi$ two representing elements of the same guy in the quotient)?

Comment: @nippon: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, states are not equal but for quantum computing they are equivalent.

Comment: I think you should edit this answer! Claiming that they are "the same" seems pretty missleading to me. For me "the same" means "equal", which they are clearly not!

Comment: @sebhofer: Thanks, I discussed this with user *Nippon* above. But you are right, I edited the question.

Comment: @MartinVesely I know, but not everyone reads all the comments...

Answer (score 7):

They are physically indistinguishable, also their density matrices are the same because $$\big(-|\psi\rangle\big)\big(-\langle\psi|\big) = |\psi\rangle \langle\psi|$$ 
But mathematically they are two different vectors. And it's better to not forget about this when doing calculations.

Comment: This can be generalized, having $\mathrm{e^{i\varphi}}|\psi\rangle$, a density matrix is $(\mathrm{e^{i\varphi}}|\psi\rangle) (\mathrm{e^{-i\varphi}}\langle\psi|) = |\psi\rangle \langle\psi|$

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

The factor $e^{i\phi}$ of the state $e^{i\phi}|\psi\rangle$ (which in this case is $-1$) is called a "global phase". It does not have physically observable consequences (i.e., you can not come up with an experiment to figure out what the global phase of a state is) and can be safely ignored.